# Calculate final position of UIView after flick using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer, swift2

I have a circular shaped `UIView` which I can move around the screen with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. During `.Changed`, the `UIView` is moved around with the user's finger. I have nothing for '.Ended'. I want the user to be able to flick the UIView, and for it to continue on its path for a bit after the user lifts her finger. The length of the path would depend on the velocity of the pan.

Is that possible to do with my current implementation of `.Changed`? How can I calculate the final position of the `UIView`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform) of CGAffineTransform, you can find the following paragraph:

[image: vector]

Let's translate that into code:

```
let transform = self.view.transform
let xPosition = transform.a * transform.tx + transform.c * transform.ty + transform.tx
let yPosition = transform.b * transform.tx + transform.d * transform.ty + transform.ty
let targetTransform = self.transform(view: self.view,
                                     for: CGPoint(x: xPosition, yPosition))
```

We can then apply the calculated `CGAffineTransform` to our `UIView`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
  self.view.transform = targetTransform
}
```

Keep in mind that the animation duration is not taking the current velocity into account. For more natural behaviour, consider taking a look at [UIKit Dynamics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/animation_and_haptics/uikit_dynamics).